# Error installing Rails 4.0.0 with Ruby 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, installation, pry

Using `OS X 10.8.4`

Seems to work ok with ruby 1.9.3.

```
$ rvm -v    
rvm 1.20.9 (master) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]

$ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p195 (2013-05-14 revision 40734) [x86_64-darwin12.2.0]

$ gem install rails --version 4.0.0 --no-ri --no-rdoc
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `pry' for #<Binding:0x007fa75a9a6268>
```

So I took a look at pry:

```
$ gem install pry
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `pry' for #<Binding:0x007f8dac196450>
```

Not sure what to do here...

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get it to work without rvm.

I followed these instructions and built/installed ruby 2 through rvm, then rails installed cleanly.

http://www.interworks.com/blogs/ckaukis/2013/03/05/installing-ruby-200-rvm-and-homebrew-mac-os-x-108-mountain-lion

Comment: Those are actually the directions I have followed. I updated the question to include the rvm version.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like something in your environment requires the `pry` gem to be installed, do you have a custom .irbrc file in your home directory?

Installing the pry gem (i.e. `gem install pry`) should fix this for you.

Comment: Good idea about the `.irbrc` file, but I do not have one. Seems like something is triggering `pry` somehow. I updated to the question to show what happens why I try to install `pry`.